# Marker animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

Im trying to implement a functionality that changes the marker color when you click them and when its closed or another marker is clicked it returns back to its default color. so far Ive gotten my code to change the color when its clicked but I cant seem to return the closed markers to the original color.

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
            this.setIcon(defaultMarker);
        });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
            this.setIcon(highlightedMarker);
          });

      google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick', function(){
              marker.setIcon(defaultMarker);
              infoWindow.close(defaultMarker)

      })
```

here is my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Jcook894/88j5ud5h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set two `click` event on your marker and the last one, set the marker color to blue.

You can click many times you want, it will always be the *blue* at the end.

So, I :

- removed the both marker `click` event : `marker.addListener('click', function(){})`
- moved the `.setIcon(highlightedMarker)` in the Google Maps `click` listener
- add a `infowindow.closeclick` event : when a infowindow is closed, the event is triggered.
- add a custom property to your `infowindow`object which is the `marker` object : `infoWindow.marker = marker;`

***Note**: Before set this new `marker` property to the infowindow object, check if it's not null. If not, there is a marker actually highlighted : set the default color*

```
if (infoWindow.marker) {
  infoWindow.marker.setIcon(defaultMarker);
}
```

- change the marker color by the default one in the `infowindow.closeclick` event : `this.marker.setIcon(defaultMarker);`

---

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', ( function(marker, location){
  return function() {
     console.log("that " + location);
     streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(marker.position, streetRadius, getStreetData);

      // Infowindow
        // Marker
      if (infoWindow.marker) {
        infoWindow.marker.setIcon(defaultMarker);
      }
      infoWindow.marker = marker;

      // Open
      infoWindow.open( map, marker);
      infoWindow.setContent("<div>" + marker.title + "</div><div id='pano'></div><div><a href=" + location.url + ">"+ location.url +"</a></div>");

      // Set the marker color
  }
})(marker, locationArray[i]));

google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',function(){
  this.marker.setIcon(defaultMarker);
});
```

[Here the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88j5ud5h/8/)

Comment: Thank you, but im also trying to make it so the if you click on another marker it, the previous marker returns to the default color, would I implement this in the same add listener?

Comment: Hmm I was pretty sure that the `closeclick` event was triggered but is not. I check that

Comment: Got it ! Answer edited and my fiddle too. I really wanted to avoid a loop in all markers to reset the color.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it was used in a if statement but I was putting it in the closeclick event.

Comment: Referring to the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=fr#InfoWindow), the `closeclick ` event is fired when the close button was clicked. That wasn't your last issue ;). You're welcome !